# Is it possible to disable font faces in Markdown for tables only?

Tags: markdown, markdown-mode, gfm-mode

I really like the `markdown` mode in Emacs (`markdown-mode.el v2.4-dev`) but when I have monospace in table cells the columns get out of alignment.  Not only that, but at times the rendering kind of jerks around.  I'd prefer if it just didn't do any font changes in tables.  Is that some kind of configuration?  Alternatively, could I disable font-faces for the whole mode?